# Bound on roots of complex equation

Tags: complex-analysis

How to show that all roots of $ z^7 - 5z^3 + 12 = 0 $ lie between $ |z| = 1 $ and $ |z| = 2 $?

Comment: Rouché's theorem should help.

Comment: What did you try? If you know Rouche's theorem then it should be easy.

Comment: I didn't know Rouche's theorem. Hence had no idea where to even start. I am looking at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $|z|\le 1$, $12>5+1\ge|z^7-5z^3|$. No roots there.

Rescale the equation with $z=2w$
$$
128w^7-40w^3+12=0
$$
Because of $128>40+12$ there are also no roots $|w|\ge1$ resp. $|z|\ge 2$.

---

One can get a better handle on the root size by using finer inequalities.
If a root is outside  $|z|>\frac32$, then 
$$
|z^7|\le 5|z|^3+12\le (5+\tfrac{32}9)|z|^3
$$ 
which gives $|z|\le \sqrt[4]{9}=\sqrt{3}=\frac74\sqrt{\frac{48}{49}}$.

If a root is to be found within $|z|\le\frac54$, then
$$
12\le |z|^7+5|z|^3\le(5+\tfrac{625}{256})|z|^3<(7+\tfrac12)|z|^3
$$
so that $|z|\ge\sqrt[3]{\frac{8}{5}}=\frac65\sqrt[3]{\frac{25}{27}}$.